# Characteristic polynomial of linear operator restricted to an Eigenspace.

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization

**Prop:** Suppose that $E_\lambda$ is an eigenspace of a linear operator $T$ with dimension $d$. Then $(t-\lambda)^d$ divides $\chi_T$.

So I already know that if $T$ is our linear operator, if we consider the restriction of $T$ onto a $T$-invariant subspace, then $\chi_{T|_{E_\lambda}}$ is going to divide the characteristic polynomial of $T$. **My question** is why is it that
$$
\chi_{T|_{E_\lambda}} = (t-\lambda)^d.
$$
I understand that as an Eigenspace $T$ acts on vectors in $V$ as multiplication by $\lambda$, but I don't see why this implies the form of the characteristic polynomial of the restriction. Is there a way that I can justify for an eigenbasis $\beta$ that
$$
[T|_{E_\lambda}]_\beta^\beta = \begin{pmatrix}
\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & \lambda & ... & 0 \\
0 & & \ddots & \\
0 &... &  & \lambda
\end{pmatrix}
$$
which in my mind would give
$$
\det [t \cdot I - T|_{E_\lambda}]_\beta^\beta = \det \begin{pmatrix}
t-\lambda & 0 & ... & 0 \\
0 & t-\lambda & ... & 0 \\
0 & & \ddots & \\
0 &... &  & t-\lambda
\end{pmatrix} = (t-\lambda)^d.
$$
If I left out any necessary background information let me know and I will fill it in. Thanks in advance for any help and clarifications!

Comment: Wouldn't any basis for $E_{\lambda}$ work? You already know $Tx=\lambda x$ for $x \in E_\lambda$, so $T|_{E_{\lambda}}$ is just $\lambda I$.

Comment: I think it hadn't clicked in my mind! So just to be sure I understand if we take *any* basis $\beta = \{w_1,...,w_d\}$ for the eigenspace, because $T$ acts by multiplication we know that $[T(w_i)]_\beta = \lambda$ in the $i$'th row of the column of the representing matrix.

Comment: Yes, the matrix for $\lambda I$ is the same under any basis.